# Modifying bootstrap.css

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I want to edit an HTML page which uses bootstarp.css. The line containing

```
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-md" value="Create">
```

refers to

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  padding: 4px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  *margin-left: .3em;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 20px;
  ..
}
```

in bootstrap.css. However, as I change the `font-size`, I don't see any change in the browser after refresh. What is the issue then?

Comment: Maybe its blocked by other classes?

Comment: So how can I find out that?

Comment: inspector view in your browser

Comment: You might be using `bootstrap.min.css` in your application. Check it and if so, make the same change in the same file also. Otherwise, minify the `bootstrap.css` using  https://cssminifier.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **should not** modify or in any way make changes to Bootstrap's default CSS-file, as you can pretty easily mess things up AND you're off with a lot easier practice if you **do your own** CSS-file and use it to overwrite those defaults.

What this basically means is that you make a `myown.css` file and include it **AFTER** the Bootstrap's CSS.

You can then easily overwrite the styles set in default with your own, without the need for any `!important` stuff that is absolutely not recommended when you're working around with a framework.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying any library files is not a good practice. So you better make a duplicate of the same styles and put in your local styles files. You can use `!important` with styles to make sure the overriding of the styles in `bootstrap.css`

```
.btn {
  font-size: 24px !important;
}
```

Comment: This practice is not much better, because using `!important` is making your projects CSS really messy and using mediaqueries can be a hassle. Also, you do not need to copy the default CSS-stylings, that's just a waste of bandwidth as the browser loads both of the CSS files - and it is a lot easier to just type in the things you need in your own custom.css file :)